# Correcting the XML encoding

Tags: python, xml, perl, encoding

I have a xml with encoding tag set to 'utf-8'.  But, it is actually iso-8859-1.

Programatically, how do I detect this in perl and python?  and how do I decode with a different coding?

In perl, I tried

```
$xml = decode('iso-8859-1',$file)
```

but, this does not work.

Comment: Do you have a sample XML file that you fail to parse?  I'm starting to get confused between the declared encoding and the "is actually".

Answer (score 4):

Miscoding is notoriously tricky to detect, as random binary data often represents valid strings in many many encodings.

In Perl, the easiest thing you could try would be to attempt to decode it as utf-8 and check for failures.  (it only works this way round; a utf-8 encoded western-language document is almost always a valid iso-8859-1 document as well)

```
my $xml = eval { decode_utf8( $file, FB_CROAK ) };
if ( $@ ) { is_probably_iso-8859-1_instead }
```

Now you've detected the problem, you've got to work around it.  This will most likely depend on the parser library you're using, but some generics ought to apply.

If there's no XML declaration or MIME-type, the Perl native encoding will be used, so the code you copied should do the trick.

If there's a mistaken XML declaration, you could either override it using any facility your XML decoding library provides, or just replace it manually before handing it over.

```
# assuming it's on line 1:
$contents =~ s/.*/<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>/;
```

Comment: Thanks JB. I am using simpleXML for perl.  It does not decode when I use the above code when encoding is set to utf-8. Any thoughts?

Comment: Never heard of it, and it seems to be easy to confuse with a PHP library.  Would you have a direct link?

Comment: (1) about "a utf-8 encoded western-language document is almost always a valid iso-8859-1" ... in fact, **any file** (any language, any encoding) can be "successfully" (but not often meaningfully) decoded as iso-8859-1. (2) If there is no XML declaration, the parser should use UTF-8. Anything else is against the XML spec.

Comment: @John, regarding (1), even including C0 and C1 in iso-8859-1, a few octets remain very debatable as to whether they decode "successfully".  Notably: 127 (neither in ISO/IEC 8859-1 nor C0), 128, 129, 153.  Disclaimer: I haven't read the actual standard, only Wikipedia.

Comment: @JB: What matters is what happens in practice; see e.g. http://unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/ISO8859/8859-1.TXT ... if a software encoding/decoding didn't do a 1-1 mapping for all 256 codepoints, people world-wide would be screaming their peripherals off.

Answer (score 1):

The general procedure should be the same no matter what language:

Open your file, read the raw bytes into a string.

Attempt to decode the raw_bytes as UTF-8, with an option that checks for errors or raises an exception if it is not valid UTF-8.

The chance that a file of meaningful Unicode text of reasonable length successfully encoded as ISO-8859-1 will pass this UTF-8 test is very low (unless of course it's ASCII which is a subset of both ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8).

If the test fails, strip off the XML declaration if it exists. Prepend this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
```

By the way, are you sure you actually have ISO-8859-1 data and not CP1252 data (from a Windows platform)?

Comment: The perl/python code was able to read when I changed encoding to iso-8859-1. Its linux, so I can confirm it is not CP1252?

Comment: btw, rightly said.  I have 2 options.
1.  To change the encoding of xml.  I am using (http://code.google.com/p/java-xmlbuilder/), in which I don't know how to change the encoding.
2.  I need to decode the wrongly encoded xml to ISO-8859-1.  Which I am trying using decode(in perl)

Answer (score 1):

It goes without saying, of course, that finding and correcting the root cause of a data corruption is always better than trying to detect and repair the corruption after the event.

Apart from that, the main point to make is that your file isn't XML so you can't fix it using XML tools. You need to attack it at the character or binary level. As others have said, step 1 is to detect that it's not valid UTF-8; step 2 is to strip off the incorrect XML declaration and replace it with a correct one. Neither of those should be particularly difficult.